# How to merge / overwrite columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've currently got two CSV files. One of them (f1) has ~1000 unique IDs in a column, and the other (f2) is a subset with ~50 unique IDs in a column of the same name.

I'd like to merge these based on ID, but when f1 and f2 have columns with the same name, I'd like to choose the information in the f2 column. When I run my current merge function

```
merged = f1.merge(f2, on='KeyID', how='left');
```

columns with the same name are generated twice, with a _x and a _y version. Is there a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [combine_first()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html)

```
f2.set_index('KeyID').combine_first(f1.set_index('KeyID'))
```

Comment: good answer but not super robust. This breaks down if the  data you want to preserve is numeric and the dataframe structure is flattened

Answer (score 1):

Combine_first method only take the elements of right dataframe when left dataframe position is empty or null. I think that the goal of the question is to choose the right information ever. For this:
        We should make an header intersection between the two dataframes. After that remove of that interesection the merge key. Last there is not duplicate keys, we have "overrided" the left columns with the right columns

```
hdr_left = set(left_df)
hdr_right = set(right_df)
common_hdr = hdr_left.intersection(hdr_right)
common_hdr.remove('primary_key')
common_hdr = list(common_hdr)
left_df_to_merge = left_df[left_df.columns.difference(common_hdr)]
merged_with_right_override = pd.merge(left_df_to_merge, right_df, on='primary_key', how='left')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just append f1 to f2 and drop all duplicates:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[['A', 442],
                         ['B', 998],
                         ['C', 45],
                         ['F', 777]]
                   , columns=['KeyID', 'Info'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[['A', 12],
                        ['B', 77],
                        ['C', 6556],
                        ['D', 33],
                        ['E', 876]
                        ]
                  ,columns=['KeyID', 'Info'])


df_new = df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates(subset='KeyID')
print(df_new)
```